# $\varphi(x)= \min\{\||x-u\||^2 ; u \in U \}$ is a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

Let $V$ be a finitely generated Euclidean vector space, $U \subset V$ a $\mathbb {R}$ -subvector space. The mapping $\varphi: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is through

$\varphi(x)= \min\{\||x-u\||^2 ; u \in U \}$

defined. Now I need to show that $\varphi$ is a quadratic form on $V$.

So show following properties:

1. $q(a x)=a^{2} q(x)  \quad \forall a \in K, \forall x \in V $
2. $q(x+y)+q(x-y)=2 q(x)+2 q(y) \quad \forall x, y \in V$

Here is what I got for 1.:

$\min\{\||ax-u\||^2 : u \in U\} = ... = \min\{-2a \langle x, u \rangle + a^2 \langle x,x \rangle + \langle u,u \rangle \}$

In the end I got this for 2.:

$\min\{2(\langle x, y\rangle- \langle x, u\rangle - \langle y, u\rangle)\} + \min \{2(- \langle x, y\rangle - \langle x, u\rangle + \langle y, u \rangle)\} = 2 \min\{-2 \langle x, u\rangle) + 2 \min\{-2 \langle y, u \rangle\}$

After several attempts of calculations, I'm done with my ideas to both of them. Maybe someone can give me the name of the problem so I can look it up online.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Geometric intuition should tell you that the operator $\phi$ gets the squared distance between the vector $x$ and its projection onto the subspace $U$. Now note that projection is a linear operator.

Comment: Equation (1), which should have $|a|^2$, is clear for $a=0$. For $a\neq 0$, note that if $u_a$ gives the minimum for $\|ax-u\|^2$, then $|a|^{-2}g(ax)=|a|^{-2}\|ax-u_a\|^2=\|x-a^{-1}u_a\|^2\geq g(x)$. And if $u$ gives the minimum of $\|x-u\|^2$, then $g(x)=\|x-u\|^2=|a|^{-2}\|ax-au\|^2\geq |a|^{-2}g(ax)$. Therefore $g(ax)=|a|^2g(x)$.

Comment: I got this for $u_a$ as the minimum: $|a|^{-2}g(ax) = |a|^{-2} \|| ax- u_a \||^2 = \|| |a|^{-1}x - |a|^{-2}u_a\||^2$. What can I say about my  $g(x)$ now? Is my calculation wrong? @NDB

Comment: That $|a|^{-1}$ that you got at the end, inside the $\|\cdot\|^2$, shouldn't be there. The $|a|^{-2}$ enters with exponent $-1$ only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment, define the projection operator $\pi_U$ as the projection of any vector $x$ onto the subspace $U$. (In details, you may pick an arbitrary orthonormal basis $u_1,\cdots,u_k$ of $U$ and you can concretely define
$$\pi_U:V\ni x\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^k\langle x, u_i\rangle u_i$$
But this is perhaps not necessary for your current purpose). Now prove that
$$\phi(x)=\langle x - \pi_U(x), x - \pi_U(x)\rangle \tag{1}$$
by, for example, writing out the complete orthonormal basis as $u_1,\cdots,u_k,u_{k+1},\cdots,u_n$ where the first $k$ vectors span $U$, and then rewriting $\|x-u\|^2$ under this set of coordinates as
$$\langle x, x \rangle + \sum_{i=1}^k \langle u, u_i\rangle^2-2\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x, u_i \rangle\langle u, u_i \rangle = \text{constant} + \sum_{i=1}^k \langle u, u_i\rangle^2-2\sum_{i=1}^k\langle x, u_i \rangle\langle u, u_i \rangle$$
In the above, treating $x$ as fixed and optimising over each $\{\langle u, u_i\rangle\}_{i=1}^n$ gives the optimal solution $\langle u, u_i\rangle=\langle x, u_i\rangle$, and therefore $u=\pi_U(x)$ indeed minimises $\|x-u\|^2$,  which proves the equation $(1)$.

Note that the existence and the minimising property of the projection operator is guaranteed in any Hilbert space, so the actual proof *can* be much more general than my current version.